# Simple use of Fouladgar's Eloquent Builder class return error "it is not an interface"

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, advanced-search

I am having a problem creating a simple filter to use the Eloquent Builder class. Returns me the error

> App\EloquentFilters\Property\RoomsFilter cannot implement Fouladgar\EloquentBuilder\Support\Foundation\Contracts\Filter - it is not an interface

basically copied and pasting from how to get started

```
<?php
namespace App\EloquentFilters\Property;
use Fouladgar\EloquentBuilder\Support\Foundation\Contracts\Filter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
class RoomsFilter implements Filter
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('rooms', $value);
    }
}
```

Thanks guys for the help

Comment: It is a general PHP error, likely the code sample is wrong. Go to the Filter class and check if its actually an `interface` (which apparently it isnt). Then dig through the rest of the Fouladgar module and see if you can find the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend it, not implement it, as the error is saying.

Change:

```
 class RoomsFilter implements Filter
{ }
```

to

```
class RoomsFilter extends Filter
{ }
```

From the [gitHub repo](https://github.com/mohammad-fouladgar/eloquent-builder):

> Writing a filter is simple. Define a class that **extends** the Fouladgar\EloquentBuilder\Support\Foundation\Contracts\Filter abstract class. This class requires you to implement one method: apply.

Comment: I just looked at that 'how to get started page' you were looking at, and it appears to be out of date and shows the wrong code based on what I'm seeing at the repo.  Suggest you `extend` it as per the current instructions (quoted) on the repo :)

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I was even ashamed to be so simple.

Comment: No problem - it's not simple when the tutorial is incorrect :)